# Chrome Extension: Context menu OnClickData

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have been scanning the chromium blog for sometime and have yet to find a answer to this question.

Setup situation: A user sees a link on a web page and right clicks. They then click on the context menu item and the extension will then grab the id/name of the anchor element.

So far I have only been able to pull the href or srcUrl from the element. I can parse the url string to get what I need but there has to be another way. [Source](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/contextMenus.html#type-OnClickData)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue: http://crbug.com/39507. Please star it! The suggested workaround (see the crbug) to keep track of the last right-clicked element sounds reasonable to me.