# getAttribute in addition to getElementsByTagName not working in a chrome extension js script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm desperately trying to make a chrome extension, which is supposed to save the link title to database. For that purpose, I've created the following javascript file:

**mysu.js**

```
var linkTitle;
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  var urls= document.querySelectorAll('a.url');
  for(i=0,len=urls.length;i<len; i++) {
    urls[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
      chrome.tabs.create({url: this.href});
    }, false);
  }
  var a=document.getElementsByTagName('a');
  for (i=0,len=a.length;i<len;i++) {
    a[i].addEventListener('contextmenu', function() {
      var tmpThis = this;
      var tmpTitle = tmpThis.getAttribute('title').trim();
      alert(tmpTitle);
      var tmpText = tmpThis.textContent.trim();
      var tmpImg = tmpThis.childNodes('img').firstChild;
      if ((tmpTitle != null) && (tmpTitle.length > 0)) {
        linkTitle = tmpTitle;
      } else if ((tmpText != null) && (tmpText.length > 0)) {
        linkTitle = tmpText;
      } else if (tmpImg != null) {
        linkTitle = tmpImg.getAttribute("alt");
      }
    });
  };
}, false);


chrome.contextMenus.create({'title': 'Add to mySU bookmarks', 'contexts': ['link', 'page'], 'onclick': mySUBookmark});

function mySUBookmark() {
 alert(linkTitle);
}
```

Of course, I'm trying to debug with alert() first. However, whatever I do, I get an undefined. I tried to copy this behaviour from another extension which I know does this. What am I missing?

Regards,

K.

PS: Below is my manifest file, in case it helps:

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "name" : "mySU",
  "description" : "mySU",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "images/mysu.png",
    "default_popup": "html/mysu.html",
    "default_title": "Select page to navigate to..."
  },
  "permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "contextMenus",
    "storage",
    "http://mysu.sabanciuniv.edu/*",
    "http://*.sabanciuniv.edu/*"
  ],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["js/mysu.js"]
  },
  "icons": {
    "128": "images/mysu.png"
  },
  "version": "1.0",
  "minimum_chrome_version": "9",
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

Comment: What is the execution context of this? Can you post your manifest.json?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to execute the first part of your code in the context of a webpage that triggers the context menu item.

That doesn't happen: it executes in the context of an invisible, empty background page.

Read the documentation on [Context Scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) to learn how to do so. You can put that into a js file, and inject it into the tab triggering the context menu.

**Alternatively**, look into the info object that an `onclick` handler for the context menu provides:

```
function mySUBookmark(info, tab) {
  console.log(info);
}
```

This might provide what you seek without extra code. Though, [maybe not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7972455/chrome-extension-context-menu-onclickdata).

Comment: So, do I need to convert that to a content script? By the way, I've tried the `console.log(info)` approach, it didn't give me what I want.

Comment: I converted it to a content script, still no :S

Comment: Define "converted", it would require significant reworking. I don't think we can help further while sticking to StackOverflow's format.

Comment: In my manifest.json, I moved my HTML to `background` block, and js file into `content_scripts` block.

Comment: This indicates lack of minimal understanding.

Comment: My manifest file is like the following now. Will it not work?   `"background": {
    "page": "html/mysu.html"
  },
  "content_scripts":
    [{
    "matches":["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
    "js": ["js/mysu.js"]
    }],` (Sorry for the formatting)